# issue with including libltdl/lt_system.h library

Tags: c++, linux, libltdl

I am working on a c++ project on my computer that is running on Linux.
When i cloned my project to another computer that is running on Windows
i can't run my project any more.

## I got the following error:

```
fatal error: libltdl/lt_system.h: No such file or directory
#include <libltdl/lt_system.h>
```

Is it a way to include this library? or is it possible only in computer that run on Linux.